# Array index evaluated to null - Find linenumber and use it as index number

Tags: powershell

My input file looks like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXTI NF:-1 tvg-name="Das Erste HD" tvg-id="ARD.de" group-title="Vollprogramm" tvg-logo="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jnk22/kodinerds-iptv/master/logos/tv/daserstehd.png",Das Erste HD
https://daserstehdde-lh.akamaihd.net/i/daserstehd_de@625196/index_2739_av-p.m3u8
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="Das Erste" tvg-id="ARD.de" group-title="Vollprogramm" tvg-logo="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jnk22/kodinerds-iptv/master/logos/tv/daserste.png",Das Erste
https://daserstelive-lh.akamaihd.net/i/daserste_de@28289/index_3776_av-p.m3u8
..
```

I want to replace the stream with my variable `$newRtsp` and write it back to the file. What I currently have is:

```
# Getting the file
$inFile = Get-Content "iptv.m3u"

# Linenumber where a specific channel name $chanName exists
$line = ($inFile | Select-String "tvg-name=`"$chanName`"").LineNumber                                                                                          #`# dummy comment to fix code highlighting for SO

# Use actual Linenumber as Index, to override the following line
$inFile[$line] = $newRtsp

# Write back to file
$inFile | Set-Content "iptv.m3u"
```

**Problem:** Somehow, I can't use the found linenumber as index:

```
Index operation failed; the array index evaluated to null.
At E:\merge-fritzbox.ps1:17 char:5
+     $inFile[$line] = $newRtsp
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArrayIndex
```

Comment: How did you know that specific `$chanName` exists in the file?

Comment: Yeah, I missed that. There was no determination.

Comment: Out of interest, do you want to update just one `$newRtsp` or do you want to keep your personal (ordered) m3u list up to date by replacing changed sources?

Comment: I'm able to watch my streams through my FritzBox router (DVB-C) and their export `.m3u` formatting is different to [jnk22/kodinerds-iptv](https://github.com/jnk22/kodinerds-iptv) which I'm using on Kodi. So I just wanted to replace common channels with locally available streams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line number returned by [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-6) starts counting from `1`. Array indices count from `0`, so you need to consider that.

This should work:

```
$chanName = "Das Erste HD"
$newRtsp  = "the new content for the line"

# Getting the file
$inFile = Get-Content "iptv.m3u"

# Linenumber where a specific channel name $chanName perhaps exists?
# SimpleMatch is an optional parameter and specifies that 
# the string in the pattern is not interpreted as a regular expression.
$line = ($inFile | Select-String "tvg-name=`"$chanName`"" -SimpleMatch).LineNumber               #`# dummy comment to fix code highlighting for SO

# $line will be $null if Select-String did not find the string to look for
if ($line) {
    # Use actual Linenumber minus 1 as Index, to override the following line
    $inFile[$line - 1] = $newRtsp

    # Write back to file
    $inFile | Set-Content "iptv.m3u"
}
```

Comment: I tried using `$inFile = $inFile.IndexOf("$($m3u -match 'tvg-name="[regex]::Escape("$chNameFB")"')")` to find the correct linenumber, which I found [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/6mnjxp/replacing_text_in_a_specific_line_in_file/dk3xqf9?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x).

Comment: Your point is correct, but `-1` isn't needed because I need the RTSP linenumber (following line) and not the line that's containing the channel title. The returned value is already my index.